# How to handle Stream input/out in Open API proxy tool

Tags: c#, openapi, .net-5

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<Stream> ReadStreamFromFile(string fileNameWithFullPath)
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileNameWithFullPath);                    
    System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    return memoryStream;
}
```

When I trying to create proxy using NSWAg and Microsoft CodeDOM supported DLLs, Stream is created a class of complex type instead of simple type, which causes getting issues at runtime, when trying to calling service.

Is there any way in proxy generation setting to refer it as IO.Stream instead of .Stream?

Please suggest.
amaR

Comment: This seems to be ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core. Please tag appropriately if that's the case.

Comment: It seems like you just want [`FilePathResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filepathresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) or [`PhysicalFileResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.physicalfileresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0) depending on what flavour of ASP.NET you're using. Note that your code is _really dangerous_ as written, as you're allowing the end user to ask for an arbitrary file on your computer, completely of their choosing. How could attackers use this?

Comment: This is general query, and myself verifying how binary data (byte[]/stream) supporting in web apis

Comment: Well, normally you would return an appropriate `IActionResult` implementer. ASP.NET Core makes available `FileContentResult`, `FleStreamResult`, `PhysicalFIleResult`, and `VirtualFileResult`.